# NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I've used NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad but it does not work, ie, it always loads data from server as every time the data I received is different.

I'm wondering that:

1. even with NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad policy, it also obeys the cache control headers from server's response, regardless of document saying ignoring expire date?
2. What is the storage policy for `[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]`? If it is in memory only, then next time I start the app it won't have cache on disk?
3. I found this very interesting:

[NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad not loading from cache on first request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013342/nsurlrequestreturncachedataelseload-not-loading-from-cache-on-first-request)

which says

> it seems this problem only exists when there's a query in the url.

Is that a confirmed problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this topic is almost 5 years old, but I just recently had the same problem. In my case, I was using a NSURLSessionDownloadTask which, according to [Can I use HTTP caching with an NSURLSessionDownloadTask on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175133/can-i-use-http-caching-with-an-nsurlsessiondownloadtask-on-ios), doesn't use caching no matter which caching policy is used. I switched my code to use NSURLSessionDataTask and the NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad policy worked as expected.