# Can I use HTTP caching with an NSURLSessionDownloadTask on iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, and take advantage of Apple's in-built URL caching functionality. I have succeeded in getting the caching to work when using an `NSURLSessionDataTask` using the code below:

```
- (void)downloadUsingNSURLSessionDataTask:(NSURL *)url {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [dataTask resume];
}

- (void)cachedDataTaskTest {
    // This call performs an HTTP request
    [self downloadUsingNSURLSessionDataTask:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"]];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

    // This call returns the locally cached copy, and no HTTP request occurs
    [self downloadUsingNSURLSessionDataTask:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"]];
}
```

However, I need to perform a background download for which I have to use an NSURLDownloadTask. When I switch to this the caching behaviour does not occur.

```
- (void)downloadUsingNSURLSessionDownloadTask:(NSURL *)url {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
    [downloadTask resume];
}

- (void)cachedDownloadTaskTest {
    // This call performs an HTTP request
    [self downloadUsingNSURLSessionDownloadTask:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"]];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

    // This call also performs an HTTP request
    [self downloadUsingNSURLSessionDownloadTask:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"]];
}
```

[This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html) from Apple indicates that `NSURLDownloadTasks` don't call the `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:` delegate method, so it is not possible for your app to hook into the caching life cycle. My guess is that this implies that caching is simply not available for these tasks, but it is not explicit about this.

> 11. **For a data task**, the `NSURLSession` object calls the delegate’s `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:` method. Your
>       app should then decide whether to allow caching. If you do not
>       implement this method, the default behavior is to use the caching
>       policy specified in the session’s configuration object.

Can anyone confirm this hunch that NSURLSessionDownloadTasks simply don't support caching? Is it possible to take advantage of Apple's HTTP caching behaviour in a background task?

Comment: Why do you want to override `willCacheResponse`?

Comment: I don't want to override `willCacheResponse`, but I noted that you cannot override it for NSURLDownloadTasks, and suspect this indicates that these tasks do not support caching at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSURLSessionDownloadTask` performs work using a system service (daemon) that performs the download outside your application process. Because of this, the delegate callbacks that actually get invoked for a download task are more limited than those for `NSURLSessionDataTask`. As documented in [Life Cycle of a URL Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html), a data task delegate will receive callbacks to customize caching behavior, while a download task delegate will not.

A download task should use the caching policy specified by the `NSURLRequest`, and should use the cache storage specified by the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` (if it does not, file a bug). The default cache policy is `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`, and the default URL cache storage is the shared URL cache for non-background and non-ephemeral configurations. The delegate callbacks for `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:` are not a good indicator of wether caching is actually occurring.

If you create an `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` using the default session configuration and do not customize the cache policy of `NSURLRequest`s, caching is already happening.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am finding that the `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` in my `NSURLRequest` is not respected in an `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`. If I can reproduce this in a standalone app I will post a bug report as you have suggested.

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I have built a skeleton test project that allows you to fire download and data tasks, while inspecting HTTP traffic through Charles. All initial `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` requests make HTTP requests, so no caching is taking place. The first `NSSessionDataTask` invokes a request, but all subsequent requests of either type will not invoke HTTP requests, as iOS is using the cached copy. Essentially the `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` will use an existing cache, but not add to it. See the project to demo this: https://github.com/nickstreet/CacheTest

Comment: Oh ya, you should file a bug on this, and potentially feedback on the documentation - if the session ignores your cache policies, that should be reflected in the documentation

Comment: I've posted a bug report. Hopefully this will be fixed in the future! Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are using a background session, both NSURLSessionDownloadTask and  NSURLSessionUploadTask will not support caching.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` does not cache, by design.

**NSURLSessionConfiguration documentation**

The `defaultSessionConfiguration` method is documented:

> The default session configuration uses a persistent disk-based cache *(except when the result is downloaded to a file)* and stores credentials in the user’s keychain.

However, none of the other constructors are documented to exclude the above italicized exception. I also tested `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier` and it doesn't appear to do the job either.

Also, `requestCachePolicy` doesn't offer any way out of the exception either.

**NSURLSessionDownloadTask runtime efficiency**

`NSURLSessionDownloadTask` writes incoming data to a temporary file. When it completes the file, it notifies the delegate or completion handler. Finally it deletes the file.

While it could simply move the file into cache at the end, it would have to deal with either the delegate or completion handler actually modifying the file and thus changing its cached representation, or even moving the file to a permanent location it can't track.

It could copy the file *before* notifying the delegate or completion handler, but this would be inefficient for large files.

It could keep the file read-only, but doesn't appear to do so on iOS 8.0.

Therefore, it's unlikely that the system would do any caching of download tasks.

**Workaround**

Your best bet is use `NSURLSessionDataTask`, then when your delegate's `URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:` method is called, append the incoming data to your own file. The next time you use `NSURLSessionDataTask` you get the cached data all in one call of `URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:`.

Comment: I know this is two years old, but thanks! I had two versions of an app using the NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad cache policy with NSURLSessionDownloadTask(), and it appeared one always used the cache and one never did. (I believe now that the one I thought was "working" was actually using previously cached data.) As soon as I saw your answer, I switched from NSURLSessionDownloadTask() to NSURLSessionDataTask() and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working only by storing the response forcefully

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let uRLCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 500 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 500 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
    URLCache.shared = uRLCache
}

func download() {
    let req = URLRequest(url: remoteurl, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 30)

    if let cachedResponse = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: req) {
        print("found")
    }

    let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: req, completionHandler: { [weak self] (url, res, error) -> Void in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }

        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), res != nil && URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: req) == nil {
            // store the response
            URLCache.shared.storeCachedResponse(CachedURLResponse(response: res!, data: data), for: req)
        }

    })
    downloadTask?.resume()
}
```